# Record the Firefox tab as a video like screencastify on chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, record, mediarecorder-api

I would like to record a firefox browser tab through browser extension like [Screencastify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?hl=en) extension does in chrome. About Recording Session of chrome extension , [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) API is used to get the stream of the currently active tab and to record the stream [RecordRTC.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) of Web-RTC Experiment is used. Like wise, Is there any API in Mozilla Firefox to get the stream of the tab in Firefox browser.

P.S : I am asking about recording the tab of the firefox not recording the screen or window or through cam.

Answer (score 2):

You can record a tab in Firefox like this:

```js
var constraints = { video: { mediaSource: "browser" } };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(log);

var offset = () => video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints({
    mediaSource: "browser",
    scrollWithPage: false,
    viewportOffsetX: x.value,
    viewportOffsetY: y.value
  })
  .catch(log);

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
<span title="This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code."><i class="icon-beaker"> </i></span> <strong>This is an experimental technology</strong><br>Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper browsers versions. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.</p>
Capture offset:<br>
<input id="x" min="0" max="500" value="0" oninput="offset()" type="range">
<input id="y" min="0" max="500" value="0" oninput="offset()" type="range"><br>
<video id="video" height="120" width="320" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div><br>
```

Note that for this snippet to work here in the browser, you first have to [view this page in https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338487/record-the-firefox-tab-as-a-video-like-screencastify-on-chrome/).

And then, for security reasons, you have to append `,stacksnippets.net` to the list of sites in `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains` under *about:config* to allow this to work.

Lastly, you also have to set `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to `true` in *about:config* since Firefox doesn't implement a Tab chooser.

None of this would be necessary in an extension.

In an extension you would use the `browserWindow` constraint to pass in the outer window id of the tab you wish to capture.

> **Warning:** You may want to remove `,stacksnippets.net` and `media.navigator.permission.disabled` afterwards, due to the inherent security risks. SO posts can potentially steal your bank account info this way, by iframing common bank urls you may be logged in to, for only you (and now them!) to see, effectively end-running cross-origin restrictions. No joke!

Comment: "mediaSource: browser" Doesn't seem to work in FF 59. I couldn't find an authoritative source of what's currently supported in Firefox but at least this article: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/screen-capture-in-firefox.html claims that FF only supports "screen", "window" or "application". Tested and they all worked whereas "browser" failed.

Comment: You can enable "media.getusermedia.browser.enabled" in the about:config, after which FF will show an "application" permission screen with with an empty list but won't do anything else. The two very interesting and relevant bugs are: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396510 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321221. Basically "browser" was done for the now discontinued "Firefox Hello" and was never meant for public consumption. There's some hope though as the mediarecorder spec requires it.

Comment: Unreal, it does work even in the latest FF!  But only if you enable media.getusermedia.browser.enabled *and*  media.navigator.permission.disabled (just like @jib said). It won't even indicate in the address bar it's recording so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

There are [several privileged apis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) that let you capture parts of windows or xul elements onto a canvas context. The canvas can then be [captured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) into a media stream.

Comment: This could be done if the recorded element is a canvas element, How would I do for the whole html part in the document. Correct me if I am wrong. It would be better if there is an example

Comment: My answer consists of two sentences, it seems like you ignored the first one.

Comment: I tried out in that way and I am getting a canvasCaptureMediaStream and while trying to record , it records as a single image for the time till I stop the recording. The mouse movements and the operations inside the document doesn't recorded

Comment: you obviously have to draw again every time you want to update. and you said you wanted to capture the tab, *not* the screen. the mouse is conceptually not part of a tab.

Comment: So for every few milli seconds I have to capture a new stream and pass it to the mediaRecorder for the canvas to be recorded. Am I correct?

Comment: one stream, draw new frames to the canvas

Comment: This answer is only relevant for recording a canvas element, not arbitrary contents of a browser window/tab.